# files not open in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, spring-tool-suite

Not able to open the file by double click in eclipse

Much appreciate if you could advise

[image]

Comment: What happens with `right-click` > `Open With` > `Java Editor` ?

Comment: Do any messages appear in the Error Log view when the files don't open?

Comment: @user16320675 i am able to do this. but file should be open when I double click on file. This is my concern.

Comment: I understand you, that is only a test to confirm that the Java Editor is available and working, just one step to find the problem.  That is why I asked "What happens" and not if you are "able to do" it! I must assume that "am to do this" also means that the Java Editor **is** opening correctly, next step:: check Content Types associations **and** File Associations: `Window` > `Preferences` > `General` > `Content Types` - `Text` - `Java Source File` (`*.java` and `Java Editor`) **and** ... > `General` > `Editors` > `File Associations` (no `*.java`)